# Site traffic SQL query?

Tags: sql, site-usage

Is it possible to query a SQL DB to find out most accessed page, information on the user ( country of orgin etc ).

I need this for 2010 and 2013.

Comment: Please tag related version of SharePoint.

Answer (score 3):

For SP 2010, you can use Web Analytics feature built in SharePoint: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

For SP 2013 things have changed a bit, so you have to use Usage reports: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715890.aspx

Comment: This is useful information, but doesn't answer the original question.